# Configuring a dd-wrt 802.1q hybrid port

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, vlan, 802.1q

I have an ASUS router with a Broadcom chipset ( RT-AC68U / RT1900P) flashed with dd-wrt.   I have "regular" VLANS working with this router.

Does anyone know if its possible to configure a hybrid VLAN on a port, and if so how I can do this?   While I'd prefer to do it through the GUI to make life easier for the person that comes after me, I'm confident using the command line if that is the only way.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - tagged and untagged access port (specifically to run Ubiquity Access points with multiple SSIDs for different levels if access).

Comment: Not at all familiar with the default ubiquity setup. There are some considerations that need to be taken into account that may affect an existing network, and some concepts that will seem backwards if you are used to configuring VLANs on Cisco, extreme networks, ECT. 1. Avoid using vlan0 in the config, alot of routers have this internally mapped to the wan port. 2. The physical ports may not be mapped to the internal port number. (I.e calling on port-4 in the config may actually be physical port-1)  (Continued)

Comment: 3. The "CPU port" must be included in all vlan traffic. It's usually (5) but can be 8.  (Rt-66u was 5 when I did this last year.)  This is the reason I call advanced VLAN configurations on DD-WRT a jumble @#$&. Hopefully they add all the other functions to the GUI. If you haven't already, give this a once over: https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Switched_Ports

Comment: @Tim_Stewart thank you for that link - I'd not seen it. It was hard reading but gives me a clue. A "*" next to the number indicates untagged traffic. I had not seen that elsewhere. I'll have a play with it and that might be the key.

Comment: What release are you using? See if swconfig shows anything on the terminal of this device. You may find that easier to use, or at least it theoretically should be. It should be there on newer versions

Comment: No swconfig :<     (And the "*" thing I found did not help me either)